# How to get name resolution working inside a chroot of a different architecture?

Tags: qemu, chroot, arch-arm, host-name-resolution

On an `amd64` machine running Manjaro Linux, I'd like to be able to resolve names inside an `arm` chroot, which is Arch Linux ARM. Unfortunately, it's not working. I suspect it might have something to do with different glibc versions or so, but have no idea how to overcome the problem. The problem exists with both the pre-compiled `qemu-static-arm` and the self-compiled `qemu-user-static` packages from AUR.

Here's what I've done to get inside the guest system as well as what's been done thus far once inside, including the error message:

```bsh
[t440s ~]# ping -c 1 unix.stackexchange.com
PING unix.stackexchange.com (151.101.65.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.65.69 (151.101.65.69): icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=22.5 ms

--- unix.stackexchange.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.549/22.549/22.549/0.000 ms
[t440s ~]# mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 root/
[t440s ~]# mount --bind /dev/ root/dev/
[t440s ~]# mount --bind /proc/ root/proc/
[t440s ~]# mount --bind /dev/pts/ root/dev/pts/
[t440s ~]# mount --bind /run/ root/run/
[t440s ~]# cp /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static root/usr/bin/
[t440s ~]# chroot root/ qemu-arm-static /bin/bash
[root@t440s /]# cat etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 141.1.1.1
[root@t440s /]# ping unix.stackexchange.com
/usr/bin/ping: unix.stackexchange.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
[root@t440s /]# ls -ltr /etc/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Aug  9 03:54 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
[root@t440s /]# ls -ltr /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21 Jan 17 18:42 /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
[root@t440s /]# rm /etc/resolv.conf 
[root@t440s /]# cp /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/
[root@t440s /]# ping unix.stackexchange.com
/usr/bin/ping: unix.stackexchange.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

How can one make name resolution work with this technique?

Comment: Could you show us the content of : `ls -ltr /etc/resolv.conf` out of the chroot

Comment: Certainly! I've updated the question.

Comment: I see, have your tried to : systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service

Comment: Doing that outside the chroot changes nothing. Doing it inside only yields "Running in chroot, ignoring command 'restart'"...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe install also `binfmt-qemu-static` from AUR?

Comment: It's been a while and I can't remember anymore if that was one of the things I already tried. Will give it a go on the weekend, thank you for the suggestion!